# $u$ has $L^2$ integrable derivatives of order through r iff

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I read that $u$ has $L^2$ integrable derivatives of order through r iff $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1+|w|^2)^r |\hat{u}(w)|^2dw<\infty$.

The textbook(Finite difference schemes and partial differential equations, Strikwerda, 2ed, p.43) says that this is because $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\dfrac{\partial ^r u(x)}{\partial x}|^2dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |w|^{2r} |\hat{u}(w)|^2dw$

But why is it true that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1+|w|^2)^r |\hat{u}(w)|^2dw<\infty \Leftrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |w|^{2r} |\hat{u}(w)|^2dw<\infty$ ? $\Rightarrow$ direction is obvious, but I'm not sure why the converse is true.

Comment: I suspect that everything is phrased under the assumption that $u\in L^{2}$, which then implies $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{u}(w)|^{2}dw < \infty$.